# Read environment global variables (and not process variables)

Tags: python

**INTRODUCTION**

I have a problem calling a process (via the `subprocess` library) from python to run a third party executable. The programme crashes whereas it works perfectly from the command line. The reason for this is an environment variable conflict in the subprocess, namely a variable that is available and should not be (this variable is defined in the python process scope)

For instance, if in the process there is an environment variable `MYVAR = 'hello'`, but this var has not been defined in the system, this `MYVAR` would be available in `os.environ`, which is used per default in the subprocess call.

**WHAT I NEEED**

I need to reproduce exactly the process call as if it directly came from a command line (I can manually remove this variable for the process call, but this can end being a maintenance nightmare)

To achieve this, I need to read the environment/system global variables, and **NOT the environment variables available to the python process**. Once I have this, doing the process call with the appropriate environment is a no brainer.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Using `os.environ`, but as commented before, it shows the variables available to the python process...

Comment: Why do you think the "global" environment variables are any different from the ones Python has access to?

Comment: Because they are... the set of variables is different. My python script is inside of a huge framework that sets several environment variables (local to the process obviously), and one of this variables leads to a crash in the third party application call. In order to avoid this, I want to get the set of system variables exactly as they are in the OS (windows), with no modifications.

Comment: So then why don't you just not pass those variables?

Comment: Because as explained in the question, that requires explicit maintenance from my programme. Say in the next framework version, there is another variable conflict. In that case I would have to edit my script to correct it. If I take the variables as they are in the system, I don't have to worry anymore.

Comment: When your program starts up, and before it changes any environment variables, take a copy of all environment variables (these are the 'system' variables you are talking about). Then when you launch your subprocess, use the `env` parameter of POpen (documented https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to make the subprocess run with the original copied env variables.

Comment: @TomDalton, I just can't do that, I working inside a big framework and I just have voice over my little area. Passing the environment to Popen was not the problem :). Thanks.

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: The problem is: how do I get the "global system/environment variables" from python? The system-global ones, not the ones available to the python process (which cause the problems). Your idea about fetching them before they change is not bad, but I cannot do that within my project.